# Iteration through letters in fish shell

Tags: fish

In bash I can:

```
for i in /dev/sd{b..g}; do pvcreate $i; done
```

Looking for the equivalent of this loop in fish.

```
for i in /dev/sd{b..g}
    pvcreate $i
end
```

Returns ***Device /dev/sdb..g not found (or ignored by filtering).*** error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct translation: fish only does comma-separated elements inside braces -- https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand-brace

You can't do `for i in /dev/sd[b-g]` either because fish does not use character sets as wildcards in globbing -- https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand-wildcard

You're ending up calling some external program to generate that list of files, and you know bash works, so:

```
for i in (bash -c 'printf "%s\n" /dev/sd{b..g}'); ...
```

This is an example of one of [fish's design principles](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html):

> Everything that can be done in other shell languages should be possible to do in fish, though fish may rely on external commands in doing so.

Comment: If you have `jot` it can also be used:  `for i in /dev/sd(jot -c 7 a g)`

Comment: As I expected. Though I hoped that I missed something. :)